Mathematical meaning of a position eigenbra $\langle x_0 |$
Let $|x_0\rangle$ be an position eigenket. The physical picture I have for $|x_0\rangle$ is a particle located at $x_0$. Thus it should be represented by a delta function $\delta(x-x_0)$.
For $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ let $\langle f | = (f, \cdot)$ where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ inner product. Applying this to the eigenket $|x_0 \rangle$ we would informally get something like $(\delta(x-x_0), \cdot)$. However since $\delta(x-x_0)$ is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, this expression is meaningless.
How do we give meaning to $\langle x_0 |$?

This is a very good, and subtle question. I recommend the papers https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0502053v1 and https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069, and generally looking up "rigged Hilbert spaces".

If you wanted to know what mathematical spaces such entities actually exist in, you would have to consider Rigged Hilbert spaces. Gelfand triples. However, that is actually a dead-end in the analysis. Instead, the fruitful method is to vastly expand upon Hilbert space machinery so that you can define such things using limits, converging onto these entities. Then you can show that all the usual abuses of notation would work.

@SahandTabatabaei Thank you for these references.

@naturallyInconsistent Why are rigged Hilbert spaces and Gelfand triples considered dead-ends? Could you elaborate on what you mean by expanding upon Hilbert space machinery? This sounds very interesting.

I have absolutely no idea. I am simply a messenger repeating what the prophets who know a lot more maths than me are saying. The foundations of quantum theory are built upon Hilbert spaces, and so if you want to actually figure out the answers to the questions you are raising, you have to put in a lot of work to understand them.

As others have pointed out, you have to use the notion of rigged Hilbert spaces. This should be covered, or at least briefly discussed, in decent QM books. See e.g. Ballentine, Isham and textbooks for more mathematical oriented readers. Also: related

BTW: The man is called "Riesz" and for your logic, you don't even need the theorem. Every vector defines a (continuous) linear functional as you've defined it. The converse (and some additional remarks) is the content of the Riesz representation theorem.


The physical picture I have for $|x_0\rangle$ is a particle located at $x_0$. This is how the subject is taught, but it is incorrect. Quantum theory on a continuous space does not have valid quantum states localized to points, the most localized states are wave packets with non-zero width, because only those can be properly normalized. Delta distribution is just an improper eigen object for continuous operator, it does not belong to Hilbert space and does not represent proper state. $|x_0\rangle$ is just a linear form that for most kets returns a number, it has no physics significance.


The easiest way to see $|x_0\rangle$ is not a proper quantum state is that $\langle x_0 | x_0'\rangle = \delta(x_0-x_0')$ and thus $\langle x_0 | x_0\rangle$ is undefined.

@JánLalinský The OP seems well aware of all of this.

@TobiasFünke Thank you for catching that typo. It seems rigged Hilbert spaces are what I'm looking for.

The theorem of Riesz states that any bounded ($\equiv$ continuous) linear functional $f: \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ on a (complex) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ can be written in the form $f(\psi)=\langle \phi_f | \psi \rangle$ for all $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$ with a uniquely determined vector $\phi_f \in \mathcal{H}$. In addition, $|\!|\phi_f |\!|= |\!| f |\!|$ holds.
However, this does not mean that unbounded linear functionals do not make sense. The difference is that an unbounded linear functional $F$ is defined only on an (usually dense) subspace $\mathcal{D}(F)$ of the full Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.
In the case of your example with the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the mapping $\psi \to \psi(x_0)$ does not make sense for arbitrary  elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as the latter are in fact equivalence classes of square integrable functions differing only on a null set $N\subset \mathbb{R}$. However, choosing e.g. the dense domain $\mathcal{D}(F_{x_0})$ of continuous elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $F_{x_0}(\psi) = \psi(x_0)$ defines an unbounded linear functional $F_{x_0}: \mathcal{D}(F_{x_0}) \to \mathbb{C}$. In this case, $\psi \in \mathcal{D}(F_{x_0}$) means that there exists a continuous representative $\psi$ such that the value $\psi(x_0) \in \mathbb{C}$ makes indeed sense. Clearly, $F_{x_0}$ is unbounded, as one can choose a sequence $(\psi_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of unit vectors $\psi_n \in \mathcal{D}(F_{x_0})$ with $\psi_n(x_0) \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$. The fact that $F_{x_0}$ is unbounded is also the reason why the theorem of Riesz cannot be applied and the formal expression $F_{x_0}(\psi)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \, \delta(x-x_0) \psi(x)$  (for $\psi \in \mathcal{D}(F_{x_0}$)) requires the distribution $\phi_{F_{x_0}}(x) = \delta(x-x_0) \notin L^2(\mathbb{R}) $.

Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.
